# How to compare value input with new input javascript

Tags: javascript, input, compare

I'd like to know how to do in javascript the following:
I've got a field on a form with a value (float) stored in the db, let's call it initial.  Each time the user change the value of this field, let's call it new,  Id like to compare the new and initial values before submitting the form?
How can I achieve that?

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Since no HTML was given, lets assume your `input` has id of `txtInput`

```
var initial = "someDBVal";

//assigning a change handler to your input
document.getElementById("txtInput").onchange = function() {
    var newx = document.getElementById("txtInput").value;

    if (newx == initial) {
        alert("they match");
    } else {
        alert("no match");
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/Bdpxd/

Comment: The problem here is that the initial value is like a constant. In my case, the value of the field is retrieve from a db and after the user modified its value, I lost its value for my checks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var initial = 0.123;
document.getElementById("theinput").onchange = function() {
    var _new = document.getElementById("theinput").value;

    if (parseFloat(_new) == parseFloat(initial)) {
        console.log("equal");
    } else {
        console.log("not equal");
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that the initial value is like a constant. In my case, the value of the field is retrieve from a db and after the user modified its value, I lost its value in order to make my checks.